# Proximity of multiword phrases in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, proximity

Say you have two multi word phrases, one is "quick fox" and the other is "lazy brown".

The goal is to have 0 slop within the phrases and >0 slop between the phrases. Such that "quick fox" and "lazy brown" are matched without any extra words within either phrase but there could be multiple words between the two phrases.

So that the following should match:

1. quick fox jumped over the lazy brown dog
2. quick fox jumped 10 feet over and above the lazy brown dog
3. quick fox jumped 10 feet over and above the lazy brown cat
4. quick fox hopped over the lazy brown dog

But these will not:

5. quick fast fox jumped over the lazy brown dog
6. quick fox jumped over the lazy slow brown dog

Any ideas? I've been experimenting with span_near and span_multi but haven't gotten anywhere yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is phrase query. Phrase query will make sure only if the words remain adjacent , then the match occurs. That is , it only tolerates a slop of 0.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "text": "quick fox"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "text": "lazy brown"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Phrase query - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html

Comment: This would work for the first requirement but "quick fox" and "lazy brown" could be 5 words apart or 5000 words apart. I don't believe I could specify the slop between the two phrases with this method.

Answer (score -2):

Disclaimer: I've never even heard of Elasticsearch until just now, and came up with this answer after 5 minutes on google.

It doesn't look like it's possible to specify a *minimum* slop value for a queried string (although I could have missed something), which makes your requirement: ">0 slop between the phrases" a little tricky. However, would this simple trick solve your problem:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must":     { "match": "quick fox"},
        "must":     { "match": "lazy brown"},
        "must_not": { "match": "quick fox lazy brown"}
    }
}
```

Links: [dsl string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), [slop guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html)

Comment: The bool query is of wrong format. You can have only one must and all cases should be put up as an array.

Comment: Fair enough. Although I just had another skim through the documentation to see if I'd obviously broken the rules, and still can't see anything about it! Is there actually any good resource (e.g. including lots of syntax examples) you could link to, for future readers?

Comment: First of all , bool is an hashmap structure. How can 2 keys of same values even exist ( I am talking about must )

Comment: Depends how the compiler is parsing it - it could be a multi value hash under the hood! But since the API doesn't treat it that way, it would be nice for the documentation to actually mention this.

Comment: I think this hits the first requirement in spirit but you wouldn't be able to hit the second requirement of specifying slop between the phrases with this method. >0 slop is misleading. I mean that as a range of possibilities from which a discrete value would be selected for each execution. For example, 5.

Comment: Perhaps you should have included the need for that feature in the original question